# How to remove S2S connection?

Tags: ejabberd, xmpp

I recently tried out snikket on one of my android devices, but then removed it. A couple days later, I noticed there are some S2S connections to "push.snikket.net".

Log entries:

```
2022-01-14 16:55:49.049 [info] <0.10068.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:init:289 Outbound s2s connection started: xmpp.mydomain.com -> push.snikket.net
2022-01-14 16:55:49.808 [info] <0.10068.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:handle_auth_success:223 (tls|<0.10068.0>) Accepted outbound s2s EXTERNAL authentication xmpp.mydomain.com -> push.snikket.net (64.225.64.225)
2022-01-14 16:55:50.779 [info] <0.10069.0>@ejabberd_s2s_in:handle_auth_success:183 (tls|<0.10069.0>) Accepted inbound s2s EXTERNAL authentication push.snikket.net -> xmpp.mydomain.com (::ffff:64.225.64.225)
2022-01-14 16:55:50.966 [info] <0.419.0>@mod_push:notify:514 push.snikket.net rejected notification for ryan@xmpp.mydomain.com (rYCqkWfRza/O) temporarily: recipient-unavailable
```

I am using Ejabberd. How can I remove this connection permanently? I've tried `sudo ./ejabberdctl stop_s2s_connections` but that doesn't seem to remove it completely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's Snikket's XMPP Push Notification Service, which they might have subscribed you at when using Snikket.

I'd ask here how to get rid of that subscription: https://snikket.org/contact/

Comment: Thank you. I'll contact them but how can I remove the outgoing requests on my end? I can kill them, but they keep coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the database to a text file, and search for any reference to snikket. Now that you know what table, or what user, is referencing to that remote server, go to the actual database and delete that entry.